# How to remove the margins from a ggmap

Tags: r, dictionary, margin, ggmap

I was trying to plot a map using ggmap package without any margin, axis, labels, etc. I was able to remove the labels, and axis but have no idea have to remove the margin here. Any help will be appreciated..!

```
library("ggmap")
amap <- get_map(location = c(lon = -95.3632715, lat = 29.7632836), maptype = c("terrain"))
basemap <- ggmap(amap)
plot(basemap)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `extent = 'device'`. See `?ggmap::ggmap` for other options.

```
library("ggmap")
amap <- get_map(location = c(lon = -95.3632715, lat = 29.7632836), maptype = c("terrain"))
basemap <- ggmap(amap, extent = "device")
basemap
```

Comment: Thanks, Sandy! That almost solved my problem, except there is still space above and below the map. I'm looking for a solution to eliminate the white space around the map.

Comment: @jinlong, make sure the device has the same proportions as the map. In this case, the map is square; therefore make sure the device is square. On a windows machine, `windows(6,6); basemap` should do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

All previous solutions do not answer the question exactly and still leave some white-space.

I ended up with:

```
ggmap(yourmap) +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, -1, -1), 'lines')) +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('')
```

**Before:**

[image: Before:]

**After:**

[image: After]

Answer (score 2):

```
library("ggmap")
amap <- get_map(location = c(lon = -95.3632715, lat = 29.7632836), 
    maptype = c("terrain"))
basemap <- ggmap(amap) + 
theme(axis.line = element_line(color = NA)) + 
xlab("") + ylab("")
basemap
```